# Do existing connections immediately honor a change to the TRUSTWORTHY setting?

Tags: sql-server, trigger, security

When you change the `TRUSTWORTHY` setting, will existing connections immediately honor this change?

I had an experience that seems to suggest existing connections don't immediately honor the change but that doesn't seem right, so I'd just like to get confirmation on this so I know what I'm dealing with.

Not during a query. I mean if you're in SSMS with an open session and the setting changes, will your next query be affected by the change in that same session?

I wasn't sure which database needed to have `TRUSTWORTHY` turned on for a particular process so I was testing to see. I turned it off in one database and it still ran fine. Then I turned it off in the other database and it still ran fine. Yet the process didn't run later for another user so I immediately turned it back on in both dbs. I thought it was odd that the process ran successfully after I turned it off in both databases to begin with because I'm almost certain it's necessary to be on for a trigger in the one db to be able to write to a table in the other db.

I'm trying to change from `ON` to `OFF`.

Comment: Please see the updates I posted to my answer. There's a test script as well as steps needed to get away from `TRUSTWORTHY`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changes to the `TRUSTWORTHY` setting are indeed noticeable, at least between queries/statements, while a session is still active. A change from `ON` to `OFF` will *not* affect an executing query (a change from `OFF` to `ON` is irrelevant as the query never would have started if the setting started as `OFF` and such a condition produces an error), not even if it has an `OUTER APPLY` that will execute the "outer" expression/object multiple times. The executing query is allowed to complete before the setting is checked again. I have tested both scenarios, and the test for the first scenario (the more obvious and common case) is below.

**Test**

```sql
CREATE DATABASE [A];
ALTER DATABASE [A] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE, TRUSTWORTHY OFF;

CREATE DATABASE [B];
ALTER DATABASE [B] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE, TRUSTWORTHY OFF;

USE [B];
CREATE TABLE dbo.Stuffs(col1 INT);
INSERT INTO dbo.Stuffs([col1]) VALUES (1);

USE [A];
CREATE TABLE dbo.Here ([col1] INT);

GO
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.[tr_Here_Ins] ON dbo.[Here]
WITH EXECUTE AS N'dbo'
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [B].dbo.[Stuffs] ([col1])
        SELECT [col1]
        FROM   inserted
END;
GO

CREATE USER [Testy] WITHOUT LOGIN;
GRANT INSERT ON dbo.[Here] TO [Testy];

EXECUTE AS USER = N'Testy';

INSERT INTO dbo.[Here] ([col1]) VALUES (1);
/*
Msg 916, Level 14, State 2, Procedure tr_Here_Ins, Line 7 [Batch Start Line XXXX]
The server principal "ALBRIGHT\Solomon" is not able to access the database "B"
under the current security context.
*/


-- In another tab/session:
-- ALTER DATABASE [A] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;

INSERT INTO dbo.[Here] ([col1]) VALUES (2);
-- Success
SELECT SESSION_USER; -- Testy


-- In the other tab/session:
-- ALTER DATABASE [A] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF;

INSERT INTO dbo.[Here] ([col1]) VALUES (3);
/*
Msg 916, Level 14, State 2, Procedure tr_Here_Ins, Line 7 [Batch Start Line XXXX]
The server principal "ALBRIGHT\Solomon" is not able to access the database "B"
under the current security context.
*/


REVERT;
SELECT SESSION_USER; -- dbo

SELECT * FROM [B].dbo.[Stuffs];
```

**Cleanup**

```sql
USE [master];
DROP DATABASE [A];
DROP DATABASE [B];
```

---

Regarding which database needs to have `TRUSTWORTHY` set to `ON` to avoid certain permissions errors:

- Snarky (though also ideal) answer: "none" as you should be using module signing (please see my site, [Module Singing Info](https://ModuleSinging.Info/), for more, um, info). See below.
- Straight-forward answer: only the database where the request is coming from needs to have `TRUSTWORTHY` enabled, if `TRUSTWORTHY` must be used. This is different from Cross-Database Ownership Chaining where, when not enabling for all databases on the instance, then all databases involved in the request need to have `DB_CHAINING` enabled.

Regarding ideal (non-`TRUSTWORTHY`-based) option:

1. Create a certificate in the database (A) containing trigger
2. `ALTER` the trigger to remove the `WITH EXECUTE AS...` clause
3. Sign the trigger using [ADD SIGNATURE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/add-signature-transact-sql)
4. Copy the certificate (public key only) to the database (B) that the trigger is writing to
5. Create a user in the other database (B) from the certificate
6. Grant the new certificate-based user `INSERT` permission on the table being written to
7. `ALTER` the database (A) with the trigger to disable `TRUSTWORTHY`